# Can I build Lucene database using .NET then use ZendFramework to read that database later?

Tags: lucene.net, zend-lucene

I have a SQLSERVER database and I want to implement the search feature on PHP. I am just wondering if I can use .NET language (since there is .NET library available) to build Lucene index database then using ZendFramework to read the from the built database?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.java-lucene.html the zend lucene files are binary compatible with the Java implementation.

The lucene.net library is also binary compatible with the Java implementation.

Therefore I imagine it is feasible to write an index in .NET and read it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, but you'll need to be careful about version numbers -- Lucene.NET is currently supporting 2.9.4 which is slightly dated. Not sure what Zend is using.

Best bet here is probably to use SOLR to hide the mechanics of the index completely.